# Recreate entity framework tables, not databases?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

Through the entity framework, I would like it to recreate my tables, and not my databases. The reason for this is that I have no permission to drop an entire database, whereas I do have permission to create and drop tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is such an initializer for EF 4.1 from MS.

This comes closest to your needs:

```
class BlogContext : DbContext
{

    public BlogContext()
    {
        System.Data.Entity.Database.SetInitializer(new CreateDatabaseIfNotExists<BlogContext>());
    }

}
```

To implement it yourself:
http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/creating-code-first-database?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+zones%2Fcss+%28CSS+Zone%29