# EF6 Code First drop tables (not entire database) when model changes

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-migrations

I'm doing Code First development with Entity Framework 6, using Database Migrations, and I'm using a new database that is populated with sample seed data. I'd like to be able to initialize my database with that seed data any time I change the model.

The catch is this: I don't have database create permissions; because of this, I can't just utilize [DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg679604%28v=vs.113%29.aspx).

Is there a way that I can programmatically drop all of my tables, or am I stuck manually deleting them from the database each time?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Recreate entity framework tables, not databases?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7358673/recreate-entity-framework-tables-not-databases)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ultimately, I didn't need to delete the tables, just the data they contained.

I ended up solving this by simply truncating a list of tables at the beginning of my Seed method, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6089763/548776).

```
protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
{
    var listOfTables = new List<string> { "Table1", "Table2", "Table3" };

    foreach (var tableName in listOfTables)
    {
        context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [" + tableName + "]");
    }

    context.SaveChanges();

    // seed data below
}
```

Comment: Aren't you going to have issues with FK constraints?

Comment: I didn't have to truncate all tables in my situation, and that ones that I did truncate didn't have any FK constraints. If I did have to worry about that, I would make sure to set up my list in proper order.

Answer (score 2):

If you're not using automatic migrations, but code based migrations, you can back all the way down to the first version using the follow command:

```
Update-Database –TargetMigration: 0
```

This will follow the Down path on all of your migrations until you have a clean database. Then you can execute:

```
Update-Database
```

This will bring everything back up to date. This solution assumes you've properly maintained your Down path and seeded your data with Migrations. I do this for my integration tests to ensure I start with the data in an expected state.

Comment: I was hoping this would work for me, but one of my later migrations introduced an additional identity property to a composite primary key (for 1..n support). Ideally, I would wipe the migrations and add a fresh initial migration, but I'm not certain the schema is in a final state yet.

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the local DB or another DB you have full permission on (Azure is nice, and free if you have a MSDN account). Then migrate that final DB schema over once it's set in stone and ready for production.

That being said, [this might be helpful](http://dotnet.dzone.com/news/creating-code-first-database?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3a%20zones/css%20%28CSS%20Zone%29), but I've never tried it before.

Answer (score 0):

If you dont have permission access to the database, it may be better to address that issue.
Anyway:

```
  public bool TruncateTable(string connectionString, string schema, string tableName) {
        var statement = "TRUNCATE TABLE [{0}].[{1}] ;";
        statement = string.Format(statement, schema, tableName);
        return ExecuteSqlStatement(connectionString, statement);
    }

    public bool DeleteAllEntriesTable(string connectionString, string schema, string tableName) {
        var statement = "DELETE FROM [{0}].[{1}] ;";
        statement = string.Format(statement, schema, tableName);
        return ExecuteSqlStatement(connectionString, statement);
    }

    public bool ExecuteSqlStatement(string connectionString, string statement, bool suppressErrors = false) {
        int rowsAffected;
        using (var sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString)) {
            using (var sqlCommand = new SqlCommand(statement, sqlConnection)) {
                try {
                    sqlConnection.Open();
                    rowsAffected = sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery(); // potential use
                }
                catch (Exception ex) {
                    if (!suppressErrors) {
                     // YOUR ERROR HANDLER HERE
                    }

                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        return true;
```